# how to remove ttabitem from ttabcontrol at run time -- FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I've added some [TTabItem](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.TabControl.TTabItem)(s) to a [TTabControl](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.TabControl.TTabControl) at runtime. But I can not remove them.

the code I use to create items:

```
tbi := TTabItem.Create(tbc);
tbi.Parent := tbc;
tbi.Index := tbc.TabCount - 1;
```

How can I remove those tab items?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/27818697/960757.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can go ahead and directly call either `tbi.DisposeOf` or `tbc.Tabs[ItemIndex].DisposeOf`.

The call to `TTabItem.DisposeOf` will run the destructor code, ensuring a clean removal from the internal tab list.

Comment: It does work, but I run the code on Android, with couple times dispose tabItem, access violation pops up. I am trying to figure it out.